# Genymotion emulator from rubymine in calabash android automation

Tags: android, android-emulator, genymotion, calabash

i am launching the genymoton emulator from rubymine for my calabash-android automation

system("player --vm-name #{emulatorId}")

What is notice is once the rubymine executes the above, it launches the emulator but then just hangs in there doing nothing.

Can someone help to figure out how do i move onto the next statement for execution?

Also, this issue occurs only for Genymotion emulator. If i use AVD emulator, then execution moves onto next statement after launching the emulator

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion doesn't run in the background so probably your system command hangs until you close Genymotion.

You can try to put an `&` sign after your command to run it in the background:

`system("player --vm-name #{emulatorId} &")`